# MultibitHD is No Longer Supported (transfer funds without fee)

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, multibit, multibit-hd

I just realized that multibithd is no longer supported. I have some funds there and I try to make 2 transactions, which were not confirmed in blockchain, because I also place them without commission.

If multibithd is supposed to doesn't work. What will happen with that transaction? will it expire? will it be completed? The status in multibit is sending since December 18, 2017.

I already moved my funds to electrum and that transaction does not appear.

Also, I do not understand if the transaction is unconfirmed because it places the commission = 0  or because multibit does not work anymore.

And, what would happen if I make another transaction in electrum?

Thank you and waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had posted the transaction id we could check, but nonetheless it seems likely that the transactions created by MultiBit HD had a way too low transaction fee. That would mean that your outgoing transaction doesn't appear on Electrum, because nobody on the network relayed it to your Electrum wallet after you had reimported the keys there.

If the fee rate on the original transactions was higher than ~1 satoshi per byte, you can and should create a new doublespend transaction from Electrum, to make sure that you invalidate the old transactions that you created on MultiBit HD.

Comment: So, the best solution would be to do the transfer in electrum again? What will happen to the previous transaction, expire?

Comment: The transaction remains valid and in mempools until it either becomes confirmed or invalidated. It can become invalidated if any of its inputs are used in another transaction (a doublespend). If you repeat your transaction, you should make sure that the old transaction cannot be confirmed anymore by invalidating it.

Comment: Thank so much for your help. How do I make that doublespend transaction? Is normal as any transaction by clicking on send and placing the amount, address and commission? Where do I get (any of its inputs)?

Comment: Use Electrum's "Send from" feature to pick one of the Unspent Transaction Outputs that your previous transaction also used as an input. Since each UTXO can only be spent once, the old transaction becomes invalid when this one gets confirmed.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!!. There is a risk that both transactions are confirmed (One of Multibit and one from Electrum) and left with a debit or negative balance?

Comment: Let me explain with an allegory. When you're using the same UTXO in two different transactions, this is akin to you having a single 10 dollar bill, but promising the same 10 dollar bill to two different recipients. You can only give it to one of them. What I'm suggesting is that you make your first and second transaction clash in this fashion that thusly only one of them can become valid.

Answer (score 0):

Check the average transaction fee on the blockchain right now, and then look for your transaction on blockchain.info. If your mining fee is significantly lower that average, it will be stuck there for a long time. Eventually your transaction priority will be pushed higher, but there's a backlog of unconfirmed transaction overloading the blockchain right now. If your fee was too low, it will eventually reject the transaction and it will come back to your wallet. You can't do much at the moment right now when your transaction is in a hanging state.

Comment: My transaction fee was n/a. What I do not understand is if the transaction is unconfirmed, for the fee = 0 or because multibit no longer works. In electrum I can see my balance and that pending transaction does not appear. What would happen if I make another transaction in electrum?